# I keep getting this error when trying to install apache2 in my deepin linux

Tags: apt, deepin

```
 sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.2-0
Suggested packages:
  apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-doc apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.2-0
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 108 kB/5,768 kB of archives.
After this operation, 29.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://packages.deepin.com/deepin unstable/main amd64 liblua5.2-0 amd64 5.2.4-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 202.141.160.114 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.deepin.com/deepin/pool/main/l/lua5.2/liblua5.2-0_5.2.4-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 202.141.160.114 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

what should i do?

Comment: Start by checking whether the host `packages.deepin.com` [is up or down](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/packages.deepin.com). If it's up, try again. If it's down, wait.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's not down, I can access it using browser

Comment: I just saw that you get a 404 (file not found). Maybe then you need to `apt-get update` to fetch a new index and update old packages?

Answer (score 1):

You have an outdated `apt-get` index. One of the dependent packages can no longer be found.

You're on `unstable` so this ought to happen from time to time. Checking the files on that server reveals that the latest version of the file that `apt-get install` tries to fetch is `liblua5.2-0_5.2.4-1.1_amd64.deb` (updated on the 3rd of June 2016), not `liblua5.2-0_5.2.4-1_amd64.deb` (`1` vs `1.1`).

You need to update the index:

```
$ apt-get update
```

From the `apt-get` manual:

> `update`
>
> `update` is used to resynchronize the package index files from their
>              sources. The indexes of available packages are fetched from the
>              location(s) specified in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. For example, when
>              using a Debian archive, this command retrieves and scans the
>              `Packages.gz` files, so that information about new and updated packages
>              is available. An `update` should always be performed before an `upgrade`
>              or `dist-upgrade`. Please be aware that the overall progress meter will
>              be incorrect as the size of the package files cannot be known in
>              advance.

Comment: @UniqueKiddo did this work?